# codeigniter 3 subdonain not found

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain

I am using codeigniter 3 and mysql
when move my application to new server has subdomain
has error  after login not go to next page

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.aixnexus.com Port 80
```

this domain dev.aixnexus.com/erp of login page after login i can not load to function in controller

dev.aixnexus.com/erp/Login/dologin

```
.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.aixnexus.com/erp/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this file under application folder not in root

my path

```
-- var
-----www
-------html
--------erp
```